# How to modify base ViT architecture from Huggingface in Tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, huggingface-transformers

I am new to hugging face and want to adopt the same Transformer architecture as done in ViT for image classification to my domain.
I thus need to change the input shape and the augmentations done.

From the snippet from huggingface:

```
from transformers import ViTFeatureExtractor, TFViTForImageClassification
import tensorflow as tf
from PIL import Image
import requests

url = "http://images.cocodataset.org/val2017/000000039769.jpg"
image = Image.open(requests.get(url, stream=True).raw)

feature_extractor = ViTFeatureExtractor.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224")
model = TFViTForImageClassification.from_pretrained("google/vit-base-patch16-224")

inputs = feature_extractor(images=image, return_tensors="tf")
outputs = model(**inputs)
logits = outputs.logits
# model predicts one of the 1000 ImageNet classes
predicted_class_idx = tf.math.argmax(logits, axis=-1)[0]
print("Predicted class:", model.config.id2label[int(predicted_class_idx)])
```

When I do mode.summary()

I get the following results:

```
Model: "tf_vi_t_for_image_classification_1"
_________________________________________________________________
 Layer (type)                Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
 vit (TFViTMainLayer)        multiple                  85798656  
                                                                 
 classifier (Dense)          multiple                  769000    
                                                                 
=================================================================
Total params: 86,567,656
Trainable params: 86,567,656
Non-trainable params: 0
```

As shown, the layers of the ViT base is encapsulated, is there a method to unwrap the layers to allow me to modify specific layers?

Comment: Iterate through `model.layers`

Comment: there are only the 2 wrapped layers when I tried that
[<transformers.models.vit.modeling_tf_vit.TFViTMainLayer at 0x7f9c1bd3fac8>,
 <keras.layers.core.dense.Dense at 0x7f9c1bcedbe0>]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your case, I would recommend looking at the source code [here](https://github.com/huggingface/transformers/blob/master/src/transformers/models/vit/modeling_tf_vit.py) and tracing the called classes. For example to get the layers of the `Embeddings` class, you can run:

```
print(model.layers[0].embeddings.patch_embeddings.projection)
print(model.layers[0].embeddings.dropout)
```

```
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fea6264c6d0>
<keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x7fea62d65110>
```

Or if you want to get the layers of the first `Attention` block, try:

```
print(model.layers[0].encoder.layer[0].attention.self_attention.query)
print(model.layers[0].encoder.layer[0].attention.self_attention.key)
print(model.layers[0].encoder.layer[0].attention.self_attention.value)
print(model.layers[0].encoder.layer[0].attention.self_attention.dropout)
print(model.layers[0].encoder.layer[0].attention.dense_output.dense)
print(model.layers[0].encoder.layer[0].attention.dense_output.dropout)
```

```
<keras.layers.convolutional.Conv2D object at 0x7fea6264c6d0>
<keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x7fea62d65110>
<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7fea62ec7f90>
<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7fea62ec7b50>
<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7fea62ec79d0>
<keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x7fea62cf5c90>
<keras.layers.core.dense.Dense object at 0x7fea62cf5250>
<keras.layers.core.dropout.Dropout object at 0x7fea62cf5410>
```

and so on.

Comment: Yes it does! Sorry for the delay and thanks you!